# Creating custom fonts for TCPDF library

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I need to add some custom fonts to TCPDF library, yet after surfing internet for hours, I couldn't come up with a nice working solution.
Generally two main ways are offered to create new fonts for TCPDF library. **One** is using online websites doing the conversion; **the other** is using `tcpdf_addfont.php` and more specifically `addTTFfont` method.

With the first way, there is a great stumbling block as the most famous website doing the job is now down: that is `fonts.snm-portal`. In fact, it is not down, yet does not do the previous conversion task any longer. The second website that is [xml-convert](https://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf) just produces `.php` and `.z` files and totally ignores `.ctg.z`. I guess, my custom files are not being recognized without this `.ctg.z` extension available.

For the second way, I really couldn't do anything special, as I don't know much about terminals. I just opened the path and copied the code:

```
./tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -f 32 -i blah.ttf
```

yet, nothing special happened. This code just opened up the `tcpdf_addfont.php` file in the IDE, and no font files were created in the `fonts` folder, as it is supposed to do; There is something wrong here with this command line, as when looking inside the php file, one can make sure that in case everything goes fine, there must at least be some echoing, whether to show an error, or to confirm that the files have been created. Yet, nothing shows up and instead running the code in Powershell opens up `tcpdf_addfont.php` in my php IDE. That's the whole story. With this introduction in mind, may you please let me know how I can get `.ctg.z` file for the custom fonts, whether via the first method or the second. Any help would be welcome.

THANKS in advance.

Comment: Sounds like php isn't installed on that command line.

Comment: I think its installed, as when I just do a php -v in command line, it just comes up with the php version... Yet, I am not that sure.

Comment: The fact it opens the file in an IDE feels like it doesn't know how to execute the script (or the content handler is taking precedence). The script uses `#!/usr/bin/env php`, so `./tcpdf_addfont.php` should work if it's a shell that supports that syntax.